# Adding a PPA to add-apt-repository

Tags: apt, add-apt-repository

I'm trying to add the [ubuntu-toolchain-r/test](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test) with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

But it comes back with:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is odd! You appear to be using the correct syntax.

You could try adding the ppa with the full path of the PPA, rather than the "ppa" abbreviation. Try running the following in a console:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial main"
```

Let me know what happens!

**edit**: this is assuming you're running Xenial (16.04); otherwise, replace the `xenial` in the "deb" line with `trusty` or `utopic` or whatever version you're running.

Please let me know if this helps or if you have other questions.

--Nick

Comment: That seemed to work after I downloaded the public key.  Thanks a lot!
Why did the other way not work when this one did?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. It *should* do exactly the same thing, right? It's the only thing I could think of to try, so I'm glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The test ppa is limited to specific users so doesn't publish the file that makes it work in that way.

Add the normal ppa one using this, the packages should be more stable

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa
```